# Netbeans, codigo padrão costumizavel

Tags: php, netbeans

Existe uma maneira de eu carregar um require por exemplo nas classes.php no netbeans por padrão ?

Comment: Não uso o netbeans mas acredito que seja possível criar um template padrão com os requires desejados.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, você pode modificar o *template* padrão que o NetBeans disponibiliza para qualquer arquivo.

Na barra superior, clique em "Ferramentas" e em seguida "Modelos". Selecione o pacote de modelo que gostaria de modificar (no seu caso, PHP), depois selecione o tipo de modelo/arquivo (nova classe, interface, etc) e clique em "Abrir no Editor".

Faça as modificações necessárias e salve o novo modelo.

Comment: Tem como colocar uns screenshot?